# Why is CSS sorting (using the checkbox hack) not working when I transition it to my CMS?

Tags: css, checkbox

Let me preface this by saying I'm not a coder. I'm merely doing this because it's a function I need, so... this is probably a really dumb question.  I'm sorry!

I need a simple, CSS-driven (jQuery and Javascript aren't options because the CMS invalidates them on account of security issues) sorting function to operate on an ***old*** Djanga Interactive CMS.  After searching Codepen, I found something which I thought I could use as a basis, but it is simply not working.

The live website is [here](http://sordid.insanejournal.com/friends#cast).

There are many, many limitations put in place by Djanga, not just the jQuery thing, and I've had issues with it not accepting code in the past -- or just stripping it out entirely.  The use of `<form>` to wrap the snippet, for example, is there only because without it, Djanga reads the code as text.

As such, I'm sure when you look at the code, you'll see a lot of ugly hackiness.

So, if I may ask those who know much more than me... what is going on here?  What *isn't* working right?

Here is the snippet I'm using, which as you can see, works fine **here**.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 0.25%;
}
.wrapper label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0.25% 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #365DA1;
  border: 7px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}
.wrapper input {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper input:checked ~ img {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper input:checked + label {
  background: #f1c40f;
}
.wrapper #murraycontroller:checked ~ .billmurray {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper #dogecontroller:checked ~ .doge {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper #vanillacontroller:checked ~ .vanillaice {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper #catcontroller:checked ~ .cat {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Sortable</h2>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Only show me pictures of:</h1>
  
  <form>
<input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="murraycontroller">
  <label class="murraycontroller" for="murraycontroller">Bill Murray</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="dogecontroller">
  <label class="dogecontroller" for="dogecontroller">Doge</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="vanillacontroller">
  <label class="vanillacontroller" for="vanillacontroller">Vanilla Ice</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="catcontroller"> 
  <label class="catcontroller" for="catcontroller">Cats</label>

    
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">
  <img src="http://www.placedoge.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo doge">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">
  <img src="http://www.placedoge.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo doge">
  <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo vanillaice">
  <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo cat">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">
  <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo vanillaice">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">
  <img src="http://www.placedoge.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo doge">
  <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo vanillaice">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">
  <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo vanillaice">
  <img src="http://www.placedoge.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo doge">
  <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo cat">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="" class="photo billmurray">  
</form>
</div>
```

This is really intimidating.  I don't even like posting this, because I'm sure it seems like an idiotic question, but I would be thankful for any ideas or direction anyone wants to offer.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this style on your live site:

```
.overlay img {
    display: inline!important;
}
```

Remove the `!important`, it will take precedence over all the other display styles you write for your `<img />`'s (i.e `.wrapper input:checked ~ img { display: none; }`).

Use `!important` sparingly... it's meant to just override inline style that are added by javascript. Lazy devs will add `!important` to styles when they get frustrated and don't understand CSS specificity

Comment: Blast, I hit the enter button too quickly.  I was going to say... yes, that `!important` was definitely my fault, and it's a terrible habit I've gotten into while trying to get Djanga to just do what I want it to do.  Removing the `inline!important` absolutely worked, but it also prevents the images from displaying in the pop-up spans.  (Spans are being used because, for whatever reason, Djanga doesn't like additional divs.)  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JoannaMellon Do you have an example on your live site of this (images displaying in the pop-up spans)? One thing you could try quickly is to update that `.overlay img` selector to be `.overlay img:not(.photo)`. This will apply the style to every img nested in the `.overlay` that don not have the class `.photo`. If the img's you are trying to apply this style to also have the class `.photo`, then make a new class and us that